# Right method to parameterized in clause sqlite for C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a following query where I have the In clause for sqlite using C#.I have tested the same codes without the paramterized method it works fine and all is correct results. So I think something wrong in my paramter because it does not give me any results?

```
codes5 = 'DA','FG'

string sql5S = "SELECT sum(salesValue) as salesValue FROM salesRecords Where  code In (@codes5)";                         
                            using (SQLiteCommand cmd5S = new SQLiteCommand(sql5S, con, trans))
                            {
                                cmd5S.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codes5", codes5);                                
                                SQLiteDataReader rdr5S = cmd5S.ExecuteReader();
                                if (rdr5S.Read())
                                {
                                    if (rdr5S["salesValue"] != DBNull.Value)
                                    {
                                        value5S = Convert.ToDouble(rdr5S["salesValue"]);
                                    }
                                }
                                rdr5S.Close();
                                cmd5S.Parameters.Clear();
                                cmd5S.Dispose();
                            }
```

Comment: parameter looks fine to me. Is it throwing an error or just not producing what you expected? note: try dropping the brackets from `(@codes5)`

Comment: No errors generated. Its just not producing the query results. I know the exact problem is in the In section. I have tried to remove the brackets it gives Sql logic error near @codes5

Comment: what about using `('@codes5')`

Comment: nope that does not help at all.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I came upon it while searching for a solution to the same problem. Have you been able to figure it what the cause of the issue was?